# VSCode 'Go To Definition' opens new tab instead of using existing tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have 2 files open, `A` and `B`, in separate split panes. The code in `A` calls a function that is defined in `B`. When I go to the definition of the function, instead of switching to the pane containing `B`, VSCode opens `B` again in the same pane. How do I get it to switch to the existing open file instead?

Comment: The accepted answer already answers my question.

Comment: [/help/duplicates](/help/duplicates)

Comment: I mean the accepted answer on this question :)

Comment: yes, I know. I'm trying to say that that alone has no bearing on whether something should be closed as a duplicate or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a setting that enables this behaviour. In Preferences, check the box `Workbench > Editor Management > Reveal If Open`.

Info from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82767

Comment: save my life !!